# ms access query for joined tables and max in group

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to link two tables, group by ID and get the max date for each ID. 
Here is what I have:

```
SELECT t1.ID, Max(t2.date)
FROM t2 INNER JOIN t1 ON t2.ID = t1.ID
GROUP BY t1.ID;
```

when I go to Datasheet view it prompts me to enter a parameter value for t2.date

Answer (score 0):

Rename your date-field. 'Date' is a reserved name (you should have gotten a warning that there might be problems when you created t2).